# How to Close HttpsURLConnection Java

Tags: java, https

I am trying to request data from the server using `HttpsURLConnection`; I currently have the server requiring the user to enter a username and password via a prompt. In a web browser after you enter the correct username and password, the browser would save the username and password as a session cookie in your browser so you can visit other pages within site without being prompted for your credentials. But for the client which is in Java, it does not save the username and password. I am trying to use `.disconnect()` to close the connection, but I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:316)
```

My Java Code:

```
private static void sendPost(String _url) throws Exception {

    String url = _url;

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    Auth(con);

    if (responseCode == 200) {
        label.setText("Sucssesfully Scanned: " + StudID.getText());
    } else {
        label.setText("Error, please scan again");
    }
    con.disconnect();
}

private static ArrayList<String> Get(String _url) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    String url = _url;

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    Auth(con);

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    JsonElement element = parser.parse(response.toString());

    if (element.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject data = element.getAsJsonObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.get("chapels").getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jObj = (JsonObject) data.get("chapels").getAsJsonArray().get(i);
            list.add(jObj.get("Name").toString().replaceAll("\"", "") + " - " + jObj.get("Loc").toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
        }
    }

    return (list);
}
private static void Auth(HttpsURLConnection con){
    String encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((BCrypt.hashpw("swheeler17", BCrypt.gensalt(10)) + ":" + BCrypt.hashpw("Trinity", BCrypt.gensalt(10))).getBytes());
    con.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic " + encodedBytes);
}
```

Example of username and password prompt: https://chapel-logs.herokuapp.com/chapel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of Stephen C's answer I determined the swap the order of:

```
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
Auth(con);
```

So the working solution is:

```
Auth(con);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

I'm assuming `ResponseCode()` creates a request to the server if a request has not already been made, otherwise `ResponseCode()` uses the pre-existing request. Upon further testing, I concluded there is no need to call `.disconnect()`.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

That exception means that you have attempted to set the property giving the authorization for the request *after it has been sent*.

This is probably where it happens:

```
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    Auth(con);
```

and `Auth` calls `setRequestProperty`.

Asking for the response code causes the request to be sent if if hasn't already been sent.  (Obviously ... you can't get the response code until you get the response, and the server can't give you one unless the request is sent.)

---

To answer your question, calling `disconnect` on the connection will disconnect the connection.

But that's not what is causing your problem.  The stacktrace shows clearly that the exception is happening when something is calling `setRequestProperty`.